# Intercept object arrives Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a controllers with GET/POST methods and i was wondering if it's possible to intercept the object before reach the POST method on Controller.

Here is my method on Controller:

```
[Route("{type}")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Save(string type, [FromBody] Message message)
{
    ....
    return Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)200, result);
}
```

Is possible to intercept the object Message before method Save() has been called? I've created a DelegatingHandler but it's not working.

Here is how i've added the route:

```
IHttpRoute route = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.CreateRoute(
 routeTemplate: "api/message/{type}",
 defaults: new HttpRouteValueDictionary("route"),
 constraints: null,
 dataTokens: null,
 handler: new ValidationHandler());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.Add("MyRoute", route);
```

Any ideas how can i do it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already created your `DelegatingHandler` you will need to configure it as follows:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                  .MessageHandlers
                  .Add(new FooHandler());
```

Comment: I've tried it but i don't want that every request hit my DelegatingHandler. Is possible to configure handler for a specific request (the request is the same method that i showed in the post)?

Comment: @placplacboom You can do it at route level, this article has an example: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers

Comment: I'll check it again because it won't work last time that i've tried. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @placplacboom No probs, interested to see the accepted answer myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done within a web proxy after the request has been made
or you also can add some middleware in pipeline. But if I understand you right, you also can do it simply without handlers, via custom binder which will change your `Message` object.

[How to bind to custom objects in action signatures in MVC/WebAPI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/20/how-to-bind-to-custom-objects-in-action-signatures-in-mvc-webapi.aspx)

Comment: I'm guessing the OP would probably appreciate a bit more detail than that.

Comment: I've read this link but i think the best approach is to use a handler because i would like to perform some validations before proceed to controller method.

Comment: Do you have any reasons not put your validations in custom binder class?

Comment: Not at all but i woulld like to do something more abstract instead make something specific for every bind.